# Accessing next Elements Name in Highcharts Tooltip

Tags: highcharts

How can we get next elements name in Highcharts

for example

```
 series: [{ name: 'weight', data: [50, 48, 80, 70]}, 
          { name: 'height',data: [5.8, 5.1, 6.1, 6.0]}
         ]


   tooltip: {
               formatter: function(){
        return this.series.name;//i want to return here next elements name also is there any way
       }
         }
```

in the above tooltip iam returning only current element name, is there any way to get immediate next elements name there..?

Comment: what do you mean by next element?  the name of the next series? the next data point?  if you know the series index you can use, ie,  chart.series[1].name to get the next series name, or you can set an id for the series and access it that way

Comment: thanks for reply jlbriggs..oh..next series only..

Answer (score 0):

You can always use shared tooltip, take a look: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared